# $\varphi(A(x))$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $A$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let's define linear operator:
$$A \colon X \rightarrow Y$$
between normed spaces $X$ and $Y$. Also consider linear, continuous operator:
$$B\colon Y' \rightarrow X'$$
such that $B(\varphi(x)) = \varphi(A(x))$ for $\varphi \in Y', \; x \in X$.

I want to prove that if $B$ is well defined then $A$ is continuous and $\|A\| = \|B\|$.

**My work so far**

Continuity of $B$:

$$\|B(\varphi(x))\| \le \|B\| \cdot \|\varphi(x)\| \le \|B\| \cdot \|\varphi\| \cdot \|x\|$$

Continuity of $\varphi$:

$$\|B(\varphi(x))\| = \|\varphi(A(x))\| \le \|\varphi\|\cdot \|A(x)\|$$

And here out of these two inequalities I tried somehow to obtain that $\|A(x)\| \le \|B\| \cdot\|x\|$, and $\|B\|$ is the smallest constant $M \ge 0$ for such $\|A(x)\| \le M \|x\|$.

Also my other idea was to use Hahn-Banach theorem, becuase in thesis there is continuity and equality of norms, however I wasn't able to use it. Could you please give me a hint how to end this proof?

Comment: You can only prove that $A$ is norm-weak continuous.

Comment: In the step $\| B \left( \varphi \left( x \right) \right) \| \leq \| B \| \cdot \| \varphi \left( x \right) \|$, you already assumed that $B$ is bounded linear. This is equivalent to assuming the continuity of $B$. Perhaps you want it in your assumptions. Is that the case?

Comment: But I don't want to prove continuity or boundnes of $B$, but of $A$. Continuity of $B$ is assumed.

Comment: Hahn-Banach seems a nice idea but in that case $Y$ should be a subspace of $X$. Is this the case?

Comment: I had the some idea, and same intuitive problem, that $Y$ is not a subspace of $X$. I don't have any assumption like this in description of the problem.

Comment: Well, if $B$ is bounded, then so is its adjoint (call it $C$). If you take $J_X:X\to X''$ and $J_Y:Y\to Y''$ to be the natural isometries, then $C\circ J_X = J_Y\circ A$. From here, you should be able to conclude that $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you have
$$
\|\varphi(Ax)\|=\|(B\varphi)x\|\leq\|B\varphi\|\,\|x\|\leq\|B\|\,\|\varphi\|\,\|x\|. 
$$
Then, because of Hahn-Banach,
$$
\|Ax\|=\sup\{\|\varphi(Ax)\|:\ \varphi\in Y',\ \|\varphi\|=1\},
$$
and so $\|Ax\|\leq\|B\|\,\|x\|$. As this works for any $x$, we get that $\|A\|\leq\|B\|$.

For any $\varphi\in Y'$,
$$
\|B\varphi\|=\sup\{|(B\varphi)x|:\ \|x\|=1\}.
$$
Using that $$|(B\varphi)x|=|\varphi(Ax)|\leq \|\varphi\|\,\|Ax\|\leq\|\varphi\|\,\|A\|\,\|x\|,$$
we get that $\|B\varphi\|\leq\|A\|\,\|\varphi\|$. As this can be done for any $\varphi\in Y'$, this shows that $\|B\|\leq\|A\|$.